# Detected WordPress url different to what was created

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a new website in Wordpress and wrote the about page. But the url which has been detected by google webmaster isn't what I have created. I have no idea how it comes out.

The actual about page url is http://www.allwebcoding.com/about-all-web-coding

The one google webmaster detected is http://www.allwebcoding.com/about-all-web-coding/About%20All%20Web%20Coding

It also gives me an error page not found in webmaster tools.

Any suggestion on how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried changing your permalink settings to use %postname% only?

Comment: I set my paralinks as /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Perhaps, you've chosen an alternative method of confirming that the website belongs to you and screwed up there? You could try re-doing the confirmation from the beginning, and using the standard way - uploading the file you're asked to.

Comment: You mean when adding my site to google webmaster?

Comment: I have made the 404 not found page to 301 redirect to home page. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: Yes, when adding webmaster tools. Try to revert the changes you've done one by one, or even do the same on a clean installation/static page. The more you strip it down to smaller problems, the faster you might manage to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere on your website the wrong URL is appearing. Check the HTML source code in the browser to find the occurrence, and fix the problem there. Otherwise just somebody entered the URL manually in their address bar.